# Ошибка: Session store not set on request

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Разрабатываю проект на laravel+vue. При авторизации происходит ошибка со статусом 500 и текст ошибки: "Session store not set on request."
Вроде как ошибка связана с csrf_token'ом, но он у меня везде присутствует. 
Вот форма:

```
    <form @submit.prevent="auth" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="__token" :value="csrf">
        <div class="formIn__body__input">
            <input type="text" v-model="login" placeholder="Логин">
        </div>
        <div class="formIn__body__input">
            <input type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Пароль">
        </div>
        <div class="formIn__body__input">
            <button type="submit" class="formIn__buttonSend">Войти</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Вот скрипт:

```
export default{
    data: () => ({
        formLogin:'border:none',
        login: null,
        password: null,
        csrf: window.laravel.csrf
    }),
    methods:{
        auth(){
            axios.post('api/login',{
                name: this.login,
                password: this.password,
                headers:{
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.csrf
                    }
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Вот что у меня в `window.laravel`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'user' => Auth::check(),
            'csrf' => csrf_token()
        ]) !!};
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по всему вы пытаетесь использовать сессию внутри API, но такая возможность не настроена по умолчанию, то есть у Вас нет нужных глобальных middleware для сессии.

Попробуйте обернуть api роуты в

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});
```

Или можете добавить в **app/Http/Kernel.php**:

```
'api' => [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
],
```

Но вряд ли это хорошая практика.

API предназначен быть [statless](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и не подразумевает под собой сохранения состояния в сесии. Авторизировать пользователя можно через token, [вот](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) самая популярная библиотека для этого. Можете почитать про stateless vs stateful и REST API.